# How to prevent availability nodejs application via upstream port?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have nginx + nodejs via upstream likes the following:

```
server {

  listen 0.0.0.0:80;

  upstream app_nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  } 

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://app_nodejs;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

When I point by browser to mysite.com I enter via 80 port and routed to 3000. But I can access to my application directly via 3000 port like the following www.mysite.com:3000. In this case I don't use proxy_pass.

How can I prevent access to 3000 port not via proxy_pass?

**EDIT:** I'm using http module to start up application, so how could I use this approach?:

```
http.createServer(express()).listen(3000, function(req, res) {     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to either put a firewall on port 3000 for incoming requests, or (preferably) simply make `node` listen to localhost only, something like;

```
server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

...or in your case;

```
http.createServer(express()).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function(req, res) { 
   ...
});
```